# Adjust space between axis ticks in lattice

Tags: r, data-visualization, lattice, trellis

I created a simple `Dotplot()` using this data:

```
d <- data.frame(emot=rep(c("happy","angry"),each=2), 
           exp=rep(c("exp","non-exp"),2), accuracy=c(0.477,0.587,0.659,0.736), 
           Lo=c(0.4508,0.564,0.641,0.719), Hi=c(0.504,0.611,0.677,0.753))
```

and the code below:

```
library(Hmisc)
Dotplot(emot ~ Cbind(accuracy, Lo, Hi), groups=exp, data=d, 
        pch=c(1,16), aspect = "xy", par.settings = list(dot.line=list(col=0)))
```

[image]

What I want to do is to DECREASE the distance between y-axis ticks and decrease the distance between plot elements as well - so that happy/angry horizontal error lines will get closer to each other. I know I could probably achieve that by playing with `scales=list(...)` parameters (not sure how yet), but I would have to define labels again, etc. Is there a quicker way to do it? It seems like such a simple thing to solve, but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite the fact that Hmisc ::Dotplot is using lattice, just adding a ylim argument seems to do the trick.You can figure out the default scale since those two values were factors with underlying 1/2 values:

```
Dotplot(emot ~ Cbind(accuracy, Lo, Hi), groups=exp, data=d, ylim=c(0,3),
         pch=c(1,16), aspect = "xy", par.settings = list(dot.line=list(col=0)))
```

Comment: Ok, thank you, that's interesting and very simple solution. Even if I add more variables to y-axis I can still use `ylim` to scale it. It also responds well to `aspect` change.